# plotGoogleMaps html files do not open correctly in Internet Explorer version 11

Tags: r, internet-explorer, plotgooglemaps

I ran into a problem rendering a Google map in Internet Explorer version 11 that was created by plotGoogleMaps in R.  The following code is from the tutorial that comes with the package:

```
require(plotGoogleMaps)
# Data preparation
# Point data
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse)<-~x+y 
# convert to SPDF 
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS('+init=epsg:28992') 
# adding Coordinate Referent Sys.
# Create web map of Point data 
m<-plotGoogleMaps(meuse,filename='myMap1.htm')
```

When you open the myMap1.htm file under IE 10, it renders correctly.  When you open this file under IE 11 (Windows 8.1), the legend box stretches from the left side all the way to the right side of the screen, effectively covering up a portion of the map.

Here is an image:

[image]

Any help here would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received a message from Microsoft Connect today that the issue I filed with them has been closed.  I tried the above script and the html map renders correctly now. I am using IE 11.0.9600.17728.  Thanks!